# accessing the methods available in module.export outside in same programe

Tags: node.js

Questions: I am trying to access the methods available in module.export from our side of same programe

in below progrme , i have method a available inisde module.export trying to access from our side in same file

```
    //Module.export section
    module.export = {
        a: function (){  // Function a
            console.log('My name is abc'); 
       }
    }

    function b(){ //Trying to access the method out side of module.export
       // How to access the function a from this metod
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it is just this simple (only it should be `module.exports`, not `module.export`):

```js
    module.exports = {
        a: function (){
            console.log('My name is abc'); 
       }
    }

    function b(){
       module.exports.a();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to store it in a variable first, then you can access it in same file too:

```
// save in to variable, and export (both things in 1 line)
var abc = module.export = {
    a: function () { }
}

function b() {
   // access your module here
   abc.a();
}
```